# Django Python json loads show me /x97

Tags: python, json, django

Hello guys i’m trying to make my web app with django and python I’m working with jquery and Ajax, and all working fine, the only problem is when I’m trying to make json loads it convert me strings in some characters.

How can I make a correct Jason loads correctly?

This is an example how python send me the json

```
import io, json
data = json.loads(data)

[{'div_oculto': ' 1 punto de medida \x97 Método \x97 Lugar de \x97 Servicio ', 'num_articulos': '1', 'no_item': '1', 'precio_real': ' 2470 ', 'descripcion_productos': ' INSTRUMENTO \x97 (10, 25 ó 50)  (-40 a 130) °C ', 'precio_unitario': '2,470.00', 'comentarios_item': '', 'precio_total': '2,865.20', 'urgente': '0'}]3[{'descuento_gobal': '0'}, {'viaticos': '0'}, {'total_cotizado': '2,865.20'}][{'comentarios_cotizacion': ''}]
```

Comment: Everything is fine with your JSON parsing. What you see is just an [Escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence).

Comment: but how can I get exactcly the same string with characters ? when I render that it dores not render the simbol

Answer (score 0):

Everything is loaded correctly.

`\x97` is the escape sequence for [Unicode character 151 (hexadecimal 97), i.e. "End Of Guarded Area"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/97/index.htm). Those characters just happen to appear in your data, and since they are not printable by default, Python uses that representation in `repr` calls.

Comment: but how can I get exactcly the same string with characters ? when I render that it dores not render the simbol